# image watch in opencv debug

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-code

Dears,

I use visual code editor for opencv app development, I wonder if there is some extension similar to [Image Watch for OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_image_watch/windows_visual_studio_image_watch.html) available. it can be handy for development.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using gdb for debugging, take a look at [OpenImageDebugger](https://github.com/OpenImageDebugger/OpenImageDebugger)

I am using this on Linux and it works pretty good.

Comment: disclarimer: I'm one of the maintainters of the project. I edited the answer to update the link to OpenImageDebugger

Answer (score 0):

If you can use CLion instead of Visual Studio Code you can utilize the OpenCV Image Viewer plugin, which displays matrices while debugging just on click.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14371-opencv-image-viewer

[image]

Disclaimer: I'm an author of this plugin